# multiple expect in a single function

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am writing the test in protractor and I wrote a function with 2 expect statements like this

```
 this.Then(/^I should see a pane on the right with an Interactions and Remarks tab$/, () => {
   return waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel()).then(()=>{
      return mobileQADashboard.selectInteractionsTab().then(()=>{
          return waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink).then(()=>{
             return expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;

          });
      });
   });
   return waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel()).then(()=>{
       return mobileQADashboard.selectRemarksTab().then(()=>{
           return waitForLoader().then(()=>{
               return  waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton).then(()=>{
                   return expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
               });
           })
       });
   })

});
```

Is it a fool proof methord and i wanted to know weather it is right to write a function like that

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you overdid it a bit. Protractor should already take care of a synchronous execution for normal cases.

As long as your commands execute in the listed order (and it looks like that), you shouldn't need to build such pyramids.

Though, when you use `then()`, you can resolve a promise immediately, but you also start a new async task and let protractor continue with the lines outside `then()`. So, the moment you enter the first `then()` in line 2, the second part of the function gets executed in parallel with the first part (not sure, if that's intended).

About `expect` in the middle of a case: it works, though it's not best practice. If your expect in the middle fails, the test case continues until the end, but the test case status stays failed. More likely you should have two test cases instead of one.

```
this.Then(/^I should see a pane on the right with an Interactions and Remarks tab$/, () => {
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel());
    mobileQADashboard.selectInteractionsTab();
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink);
    expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;

    //gets now executed after the firt expect. In your code it's executed in parallel to the first.
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel());
    mobileQADashboard.selectRemarksTab();
    waitForLoader();
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton);
    expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true; 
});
```

Also to have `expect` inside a pageObject is not desired. To write a test case (an `it()`-block) you should a) stay in control of passed/fail and b) at the same time have no need to look into a pageObject. One should understand the test case without that.

So all in all the proper way seems more something like this:

```
it(/first case/,function(){
    this.ThenFirst();
    expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
});
it(/second case/,function(){
    this.ThenSecond();
    expect(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true; 
});
```

and then these Page Objects:

```
this.ThenFirst(/^I should see a pane on the right with an Interactions and Remarks tab$/, () => {
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel());
    mobileQADashboard.selectInteractionsTab();
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.viewAllInteractionsLink);
};
this.ThenSecond(/^I should see a pane on the right with an Interactions and Remarks tab$/, () => {
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.getTabPanel());
    mobileQADashboard.selectRemarksTab();
    waitForLoader();
    waitForPresence(mobileQADashboard.pageElements.addRemarkButton); 
});
```